# Why does Rails Console quit with 'n'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

The Rails 3.2.7 console exits if I type 'n' in it and return.  This isn't a feature of IRB; n is treated as an undeclared variable there.  Googling 'n' with rails console (unsurprisingly) turned up nothing.

Can someone explain why Rails introduces this alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is added to the main object by the `debugger` gem.  As @weexpectedTHIS pointed out, this doesn't happen in a vanilla Rails app.  Uncomment `gem 'debugger'` and `bundle install`, and `n` acts as quit.

---

Just for fun, I thought I'd toss in some of my detective work.  The methods callable in irb appear to be methods on the `main` object.  It doesn't seem like you can reference main by name:

```
1.9.3p194 :013 > main
  NameError: undefined local variable or method `main' for main:Object
```

but you can still get the main object:

```
1.9.3p194 :014 > self
 => main
```

I have tab completion enabled for objects in my IRB console, but for some reason, it fetches extra results when I don't use it on a named variable available to the current scope:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > a = self
 => main
1.9.3p194 :002 > self.
Display all 6870 possibilities? (y or n)
1.9.3p194 :002 > a.
Display all 178 possibilities? (y or n)
```

<200 methods is skimmable, so browsing through there, I could see that `n` was indeed a method on the main object.  Just to verify, typing:

```
a.n
```

kills the console.  That means I can now find out where it's defined:

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > a.method(:n).source_location
 => ["/Users/erichu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/extend-command.rb", 143]
```

I got stuck here, since that file dynamically assigns many methods, but none that I could discern with the command 'n'.

A coworker suggested I try this in a fresh Rails app, and that led me to experimenting with different gems.  After a quick glance through the list, `debugger` seemed like a more likely choice.

To anyone who's read this far, I'll happily re-accept another answer that can explain where and why the `debugger` gem introduces `n`.

Answer (score 1):

This does not happen for me with rails 3.1.3.  Is this a new bug or is there something that is getting loaded in your rails initializers that is doing this?

Comment: Just tried this on a Rails 3.0.9 app I have and the same thing happens.  You may be right that it's an initializer